# Telerik Grid MVC 2 Changing Css Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I have a SELECTABLE telerik grid with a checkbox column. When the checkbox is selected I change the background color of the row to yellow using javascript.

I would like to restore the original css of the grid when the checkbox is deselected using javascript. I can toggle the row background color but because the grid is selectable the css doesn't act the same way the default grid. This is having alternating background colors for rows and a row hover background color change.

Is this possible, and how is it done? Thanks.

Comment: Andre... it can be done yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik mvc grid has built in row selection capabilities. Take a look at this page : [Client Side Selection in TELERIK MVC GRID](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/selectionclientside).
Only adding the following to your grid

```
.Selectable()
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowSelected("onRowSelected"))
```

should work